# UI merging with GraphicDesign?

Tags: discussion, merge

So, with this merging talk, now someone had the brilliant idea that it would be good to merge UI with Graphic Design (along with just about every other discipline that has the word "design" in it). One of the GD people there complained that we didn't have a link to that Area51 discussion in our meta site, so here it is:

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374/restart-graphic-design-and-possibly-user-interface-as-design

Thoughts?

**UPDATE:** As Philip has mentioned, they've finally decided to remove UI as one of their potential suitors.

Comment: UI.SE has been scrubbed from the list linked in the question.

Answer (score 11):

I can't see this remotely being a good idea -- for one thing there are very distinct professions for UX experts and graphic designers.

Comment: That's the point we were trying to make over there, but a couple people were quite insistent that there is a large overlap between the professions.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: There is an overlap, but there is the same overlap with UX Exchange and Stack Overflow, and those are separate.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that GD is now accepting UI questions.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/how-do-i-reduce-the-use-of-horizontal-scrollbars-with-tables

"there are very distinct professions for UX experts and graphic designers"

While that's true, the best UX and GD folks I've worked with (in terms of interactive) are the folks that overlap the two disciplines.

I'm find with them being different SE sites, but not if both open up the discussions to both. That just leads to confusion and crossposting hell.

To add to it, perhaps I'd summarize it as:

It'd make sense to merge the two sites, or keep them separate. It does not make sense for the two sites to be duplicating content and competing for the same type of user.

I'm interested in GD. I'm interested in UX. I frequent both sites every day. If I have a UX question, I now need to pick one or the other or spam both. Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: GD should not be doing UI/UX questions - they are not graphic design.

Comment: If you have a bad graphic design, it will result in a bad user experience. So in order to get a good user experience, you need to get input from a good designer.

Comment: there is some overlap: good UIs use space, symmetry etc to lead and guide the eye. Colours are used to differentiate objects etc.